# Quiero hacer un dataframe con info de MARVEL

Tags: python, json, api, dataframe, url

necesito hacer un dataframe con una api de marvel, en teoria ya esta conectada y la info ya esta pero necesito que quede asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la info como viene es de la siguiente manera:

```
 {"data": {
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 20,
    "total": 1559,
    "count": 20,
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 1011334,
        "name": "3-D Man",
        "description": "",
        "modified": "2014-04-29T14:18:17-0400",
        "thumbnail": {
          "path": "http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/c/e0/535fecbbb9784",
          "extension": "jpg"
        },
        "resourceURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334",
        "comics": {
          "available": 12,
          "collectionURI": "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334/comics",
          "returned": 12}}]
        }},
```

Lo que necesito es que solo tome la info como esta en la imagen. Intente hacer como cada variable y luego hacer la tabla o data frame pero me dice que
`list object has no attribute 'get'`

Ayuda por favor

Comment: te falta añadir el codigo con el que estas trabajando

Comment: Si te dice `list has no...` entonces tienes una lista y no un diccionario y eso hace que no coincida con lo que muestras, por lo que la solución que te demos podría ser incorrecta

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que parece estás recibiendo en formato `dictionary` y necesitas convertirlo a un `DataFrame`. Debes usar lo siguiente:

```
pdDatos = pd.Dataframe.from_dict(Tu_Diccionario)
```

Comment: Se puede crear un da5adrame de varias formas y pandas permite hacerlo mediante un diccionario por lo que un `pd.DataFrame(dict)` basta

Comment: Si, efectívamente el resultado es el mismo.